# auto add reward points opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Auto Add Reward Points add product rewards points to customer immediately after purchase finished. Usually in OpenCart website admin have to add reward point to customer manually by clicking on link as show in below screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are asking for with this extension: [Auto Reward Points](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=21038)
. It does what it says and the cost is minimum. Works with OpenCart 1.5.x & OpenCart 2.x.x